# Difficulty stopping one thread from another in java

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

I have the following code and I need to stop the sound thread when the user inputs a desired interger in the input thread(lets say 5). Any help is appreciated.

```
public class crytask {

    public static void main(String args[]) {         
    Runnable sound = new sound();
    final Thread soundthread = new Thread(sound);
    Runnable input = new input();
    final Thread inputthread = new Thread(input);
    soundthread.start();
    inputthread.start();        
   }}

class sound implements Runnable{
public void run(){
    try {
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("/Users/babe/Desktop/C1.wav").getAbsoluteFile());
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioInputStream);
        clip.start();
        Thread.sleep(clip.getMicrosecondLength() / 1000);              
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error with playing sound.");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}

class input implements Runnable{
public void run(){
    System.out.println("Enter");
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
}
}
```

Comment: Look into [Thread.interrupt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt--).  In general, you should read through a class's documentation before asking a question about it.

Comment: You need to learn the Java style conventions.  A class name starts with an upper-case letter.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an input thread at all: the main thread can be used for this. To stop the `Thread.sleep` use `Thread.interrupt()`:

```
public class crytask {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Runnable sound = new sound();
        final Thread soundthread = new Thread(sound);
        soundthread.start();
        System.out.println("Enter");
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        reader.nextLine();
        soundthread.interrupt();
    }
}

class sound implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem
                    .getAudioInputStream(new File("/Users/babe/Desktop/C1.wav")
                            .getAbsoluteFile());
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioInputStream);
            clip.start();
            Thread.sleep(clip.getMicrosecondLength() / 1000);
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println("Cancelled!");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error with playing sound.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```